# Expectation of absolute difference of normal random variable $x$ and constant $c$ $\mathbb{E}[|c - x|]$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, expected-value

Suppose that we have a random variable $x \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and a constant $c$. I want to determine $\mathbb{E}[|c - x|]$. It would probably suffice to establish that the expectation is finite, but ideally I would like to get a more informative expression. I am wondering whether this might be a folded normal distribution, but I am not quite sure.

Comment: is a bound sufficient for you? or are you looking for a closed form?

Comment: Bounds would absolutely be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another bound: $$\mathbb E[\vert X - c\vert]\leq \mathbb E[\vert X\vert] + \vert c\vert$$ with $$\mathbb E[\vert X\vert] = \sigma\sqrt{\frac 2\pi}\exp\left(-\frac 12\lambda^2\right) + \sigma\lambda(1-\Phi(-\lambda)),$$ where $\lambda=\frac{\mu}{\sigma}$, and $\Phi$ is the standard normal cdf.

**Edit** To obtain the exact value, note that $X - c$ has a $\mathcal N(\nu,\sigma^2)$-distribution with $\nu = \mu - c$, so $\vert X - c\vert$ has -as you have noted correctly - a folded normal distribution. The mean is thus given by expression above, except that $\lambda$ is now $\frac\nu\sigma$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mu = \mathbb E [x]$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[|c - x|]&\leq \mathbb{E}[|c - \mu|+|\mu - x|]\\
&\leq \mathbb{E}[|c - \mu|]+\mathbb{E}[|\mu - x|]\\
&=|c - \mu| + \mathbb{E}[|\mu - x|]\\
&=|c - \mu| + \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty|\mu - x|f_X(x)dx\\
&=|c - \mu| + \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\mu-1}|\mu - x|f_X(x)dx+\int\limits_{\mu-1}^{\mu+1}|\mu - x|f_X(x)dx+\int\limits_{\mu+1}^\infty|\mu - x|f_X(x)dx\\
&\leq|c - \mu| + \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\mu-1}|\mu - x|^2f_X(x)dx+\int\limits_{\mu-1}^{\mu+1}1f_X(x)dx+\int\limits_{\mu+1}^\infty|\mu - x|^2f_X(x)dx\\
&=|c - \mu| + \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\mu - x|^2f_X(x)dx-\int\limits_{\mu-1}^{\mu+1}|\mu - x|^2f_X(x)dx +\int\limits_{\mu-1}^{\mu+1}1f_X(x)dx\\
&\leq|c - \mu| + \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x-\mu)^2f_X(x)dx-0 +\int\limits_{\mu-1}^{\mu+1}1f_X(x)dx\\
&=|c - \mu| + Var(x)  +\int\limits_{\mu-1}^{\mu+1}1f_X(x)dx\\
&\leq|c - \mu| + Var(x)  +\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}1f_X(x)dx\\
&=|c - \mu| + Var(x)  +1\\
\end{align*}
which is bounded